# Как спрятать элемент в jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

У меня есть видимый квадрат(`#square`) и такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var show = true;

  $(".top").mouseenter(function(){
    show = false; 
  });

  $(".top").mouseleave(function () {
    show = true;
  });

  if (show == false) {
    $("#square").hide()
  }
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы квадрат все-таки пропадал, если я наведу мышь на нужную точку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Условие не выполнится никогда.

```
  if (show == true) {
    $("#square").hide() // ; <--- не забываем
  }
```

почему сразу не сделать вместо присваивания переменной show значения, конкретное действие

```
$(".top").mouseleave(function () {
   $("#square").hide();
});
```

и тд..

Comment: `почему сразу не сделать вместо присваивания переменной show значения, конкретное действие` - потому что возможно на эту переменную завязана еще какая-то логика где-либо в коде?

Comment: возможно, но сие действо можно вынести в функцию например..

Comment: я изменил немного код(сначало криво написал), мне нужно что б для mouseleave выполнялось действие обратное для .hide(), а я не знаю как это должно виглядеть.

Comment: и почему оно не выполнится?

Comment: @lalalala потому что в Вашем коде на событие `mouseenter` выполнится только `show = false;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cbxdgy06/2/
попробуй через функцию, если напрямую не хочешь по событию

Comment: @Igor тоесть дальше ничего не выполнится вообше?

Comment: @lalalala на событие `mouseenter` Вы зарегистрировали обработчик `function(){ show = false; }` - это весь код, который выполнится на это событие.

Comment: @Daymon содержимое функции `ShowOrHide` в вашем fiddle можно сократить до `$("#square").toggle(val);`. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/cbxdgy06/3/).

Comment: @Regent, согласен с вами. Просто подумал так автору нагляднее.